# Tibco Jaspersoft query error

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jaspersoft-studio

[image: The error occuring is this]

I am using Driver as : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

url as : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxxxx

Can anyone help me to find the error in this TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio while creating a jasper file ?

Comment: what happens when you click on "Yes"? Do you use OPTION in your selection? I assume you don't use it, but may you post your select-statement also.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The issue was in the jar, after I provided the latest mysql connector jar 5.1.40 it works fine and the error is not shown anymore.